# How to figure out current Makefile location in gmake at runtime

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to tell (g)make to include some common initializations from a separate file knowing the relative location of the included file with respect to the main Makefile.

However in the manuals I cannot find any built-in variable that would, for example, give you the name of the current Makefile.

For example if I want to include the content of a file in the same directory as the current make file, instead of hard-wiring the location of the include:

```
# MAIN Makefile : ./scripts/make/TaskA.mk

include ./scripts/make/Common.inc
...
```

I would like to write something like the following assuming that `_MAKEFILE_` contains the TaskA.mk location:

```
# MAIN Makefile : ./scripts/make/TaskA.mk

MAKEFILE_DIR=$(dirname $(_MAKE_FILE_))

include $(MAKEFILE_DIR)/Common.inc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't the manual [give a recipe based on `MAKEFILE_LIST`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables)?

Basically

```
this_makefile := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

before any `include` directives should do the trick.

Comment: @ValentinRuano Well, it helps that remembered seeing it once, because it doesn't say "this is how you get the current makefile" anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [GNU make - Other Special Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#Special-Variables). `MAKEFILE_LIST` includes all Makefiles read. So, if you take the first one and extract the directory, you're done.

```
MAKEFILE_DIR=$(dir $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

include $(MAKEFILE_DIR)Common.inc
```

Comment: You *really* want to use `:=` assignment here and to place the statement before any `include`s.